# how to give an anchor point in Laravel view

Tags: php, hyperlink, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-blade

I am using blade templating and I want to make the users navigate to a point on a page when they click on a link. This is my view :-

```
View::make($data->path)->with('data', $data)->with('title', $title);
```

My path is being fetched from the database.

There is a link:-

```
 <a id="middle">Welcome to the user section</a>
```

Now I don't think putting #middle in make() will help :-

I tried this:-

```
 View::make($data->path."php#middle")->with('data', $data)->with('title', $title);
```

and

```
View::make($data->path.".blade.php#middle")->with('data', $data)->with('title', $title);
```

but neither seems to work.

How can i make this work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your view is just the file to render -- you shouldn't confuse it with the request URL, which is determined by routes.

All you need to do is add the anchor to the URL the user clicks to get to this location, on the end of your route. If it's not something you can determine at the time the link is generated, you should use a redirect in your logic to the URL you wish to include.

That said, you could also pass a variable to your page that javascript uses to scroll the page to the appropriate location as well:

```
View::make($data->path)->with('data', $data)->with('title', $title)->with('scroll', 'middle');
```

Then, on your page, in javascript:

```
document.getElementById('{{ $middle }}').scrollIntoView();
```

Comment: cud u expand on the last point - I think this could be a clean way to solve this problem.

Comment: Edited answer with an example

Answer (score 0):

**override getRedirectUrl :**

```
protected function getRedirectUrl()
{
    $url = $this->redirector->getUrlGenerator();
    return $url->previous() . '#hashid';
}
```